# New Replicas Lose Database Icon and Launch Properties

Tags: lotus-domino

I am making replica copies of Domino databases from an old server (R8.5.x) to a new server (R9.01) by using the Domino Administrator client doing it from the Files tab, selecting multiple databases, right-clicking and selecting New >> Replics(s).

This is something I've done many times over the years,  but the last few times that I've done it,  strange things happen:    Some of the new replicas are missing the database icon (the design element is blank), and also sometimes they have lost the database launch properties  (where they previously were set to open a frameset).    It didn't happen this time, but another time the new replica's ACLs did not come over (and only had default entries).

This only happens to some of their application databases, and most will be fine, but of course,  the ones affected are usually the bigger and more important ones.  The two servers are in different physical locations (this time they are in different cities in the same state, another time they were in different countries) - so, not sure if network latency could be a factor.

Any ideas on what may be causing this?   Anyone else running into this problem?

--- (later...) 
I also posted this on the Notes 9 forum, and Mark Gibson pointed me to this tech note with this potentially being an issue with very large files going across slow network connections (and/or with low server resources).

'Create new replica' Domino adminp request failure point for large files
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21417806

It's not an exact fit, but I think it may be relevant.  (Although the tech note says it was fixed in R8.5.2 and in my case both servers are using later versions)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the icon note in the replica on the old server has somehow acquired a readernames field that is preventing it from replicating. You can check on this with [NotesPeek](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24005686).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it is not a problem creating a new replica one at a time using the Notes client.   It happens using the Domino Administrator client (using the Admin Process).

Comment: So if readernames was causing it, the problem would occur either way.

Comment: Using the admin process, it's the server ID that's accessing the database. Using the Notes client, it's your ID that does it. If there's a readernames field on the icon note, and it does include your name but not the server name (or LocalDomainServers or some other group containing the server), I believe that could explain it. Anyhow, that's my only idea. It's an unusual case, for sure.

Comment: It was interesting to use NotesPeek on the Database Icon note.  I didn't know that it stored several items show in Database Properties, like Title, DefaultFrameset, TemplateFileName.   So, I can see why it could be related.   I didn't see anything indicating readernames was set - (not sure if  flags="JFSRnqNZ7z"   tells us)

Comment: Hmmm... Oh well. It was the only thing I could think of. I'm stumped.

Comment: more info added to the main post

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the Database Title and Template settings get lost on newly created replicas when the named master template already exists on the target server. Domino creates the new replica but blanks out those values as a defensive maneuver because having two master templates of the same name can be very bad.

Comment: @Henry -  Thanks for the ideas.  Sorry, I'm not clear what you mean.  In my case, the databases are built on templates  (but they themselves are not templates).  And the actual templates are not on the target server.